# Changing old blog urls WordPress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have looked at online.rewrite/.htaccess generators and dozens of articles and haven't found a solution that works.  In my permalink settings /blog is not in there (this site's posts were imported from WordPress.com site).  The old urls are set up as http://www.mywebsite.com/blog/2013/12/11/so-what-is-this-thing-they-call-conservation/

and I need them en masse to redirect to just the main url and the post name like: http://www.mywebsite.com/so-what-is-this-thing-they-call-conservation/

Thank you in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^blog/[0-9]+/[0-9]+/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R]
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, Jon.  I have a couple more kind of hard ones for me.  Happy to pay you for your time.....I've exhausted my .htaccess capabilities.